# How to include in the lambda function javascript aws-sdk?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm new at AWS, and I'm working to create a live stream using Amazon IVS, and I got stuck in a problem. To create the channel and update it I did I'm using an SDK for that, but to don't know to include it in a lambda function. I'm using node.js as well.
Would appreciate it if you suggest to me a way how to do it, documentation would be good.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda already includes the SDK for you to use. If you want to use a different version that what is already provided please follow the instructions written in the [following link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-lambda-layers-to-simplify-your-development-process/)

> For production workloads, it’s best practice to lock the version of the AWS SDK used in your functions. You can achieve this by including the SDK with your code package. Once you include this library, your code always uses the version in the deployment package and not the version included in the Lambda service.

If you want to go with the existing SDK, you may check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html) the SDK version provided for different versions of NodeJS.